# Normalizing nested JSON object into Pandas dataframe

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe, normalize

**Background:** I am trying to normalize a json file, and save into a pandas dataframe, however I am having issues navigating the json structure and my code isn't working as expected.

**Expected dataframe output:** Given the following example `json` file (uses randomized data, but exactly the same format as the real one), this is the output I am trying to produce -

| New Entity Group | Entity ID | Adjusted Value (1/31/2022, No Div, USD) | Adjusted TWR (Current Quarter No Div, USD)) | Adjusted TWR (YTD, No Div, USD) | Annualized Adjusted TWR (Since Inception, No Div, USD) | Inception Date | Risk Target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Portfolio_1** |  | $260,786 | (44.55%) | (44.55%) | (44.55%) * | Apr 7, 2021 | N/A |
| The FW Irrev Family Tr | 9552252 | $260,786 | 0.00% | 0.00% | 0.00% * | Jan 11, 2022 | N/A |
| **Portfolio_2** |  | $18,396,664 | (5.78%) | (5.78%) | (5.47%) * | Sep 3, 2021 | Growth |
| FW DAF | 10946585 | $18,396,664 | (5.78%) | (5.78%) | (5.47%) * | Sep 3, 2021 | Growth |
| **Portfolio_3** |  | $60,143,818 | (4.42%) | (4.42%) | 7.75% * | Dec 17, 2020 | - |
| The FW Family Trust | 13014080 | $475,356 | (6.10%) | (6.10%) | (3.97%) * | Apr 9, 2021 | Aggressive |
| FW Liquid Fund LP | 13396796 | $52,899,527 | (4.15%) | (4.15%) | (4.15%) * | Dec 30, 2021 | Aggressive |
| FW Holdings No. 2 LLC | 8413655 | $6,768,937 | (0.77%) | (0.77%) | 11.84% * | Mar 5, 2021 | N/A |
| FW and FR Joint | 9957007 | ($1) | - | - | - * | Dec 21, 2021 | N/A |

**Actual dataframe output:** despite my best efforts, I have only been able to get bolded rows to map into the dataframe:

| New Entity Group | Entity ID | Adjusted Value (1/31/2022, No Div, USD) | Adjusted TWR (Current Quarter No Div, USD)) | Adjusted TWR (YTD, No Div, USD) | Annualized Adjusted TWR (Since Inception, No Div, USD) | Inception Date | Risk Target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Portfolio_1** |  | $260,786 | (44.55%) | (44.55%) | (44.55%) * | Apr 7, 2021 | N/A |
| **Portfolio_2** |  | $18,396,664 | (5.78%) | (5.78%) | (5.47%) * | Sep 3, 2021 | Growth |
| **Portfolio_3** |  | $60,143,818 | (4.42%) | (4.42%) | 7.75% * | Dec 17, 2020 | - |

**JSON file:** this is the file I am trying to normalize and map into a dataframe:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "columns": [
            {
                "key": "node_id",
                "display_name": "Entity ID",
                "output_type": "Word"
            },
            {
                "key": "value",
                "display_name": "Adjusted Value (1/31/2022, No Div, USD)",
                "output_type": "Number",
                "currency": "USD"
            },
            {
                "key": "time_weighted_return",
                "display_name": "Adjusted TWR (Current Quarter, No Div, USD)",
                "output_type": "Percent",
                "currency": "USD"
            },
            {
                "key": "time_weighted_return_2",
                "display_name": "Adjusted TWR (YTD, No Div, USD)",
                "output_type": "Percent",
                "currency": "USD"
            },
            {
                "key": "time_weighted_return_3",
                "display_name": "Annualized Adjusted TWR (Since Inception, No Div, USD)",
                "output_type": "Percent",
                "currency": "USD"
            },
            {
                "key": "inception_event_date",
                "display_name": "Inception Date",
                "output_type": "Date"
            },
            {
                "key": "_custom_portfolio_target_347209",
                "display_name": "Risk Target",
                "output_type": "Word"
            }
        ],
        "groupings": [
            {
                "key": "_custom_new_entity_group_453577",
                "display_name": "NEW Entity Group"
            },
            {
                "key": "top_level_legal_entity",
                "display_name": "Top Level Legal Entity"
            }
        ]
    },
    "data": {
        "type": "portfolio_views",
        "attributes": {
            "total": {
                "name": "Total",
                "columns": {
                    "time_weighted_return": -0.05001974888806926,
                    "inception_event_date": "2020-12-17",
                    "_custom_portfolio_target_347209": null,
                    "time_weighted_return_3": 0.0678647066340392,
                    "time_weighted_return_2": -0.05001974888806926,
                    "value": 7.880126780581851E7,
                    "node_id": null
                },
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "Portfolio_3",
                        "grouping": "_custom_new_entity_group_453577",
                        "columns": {
                            "time_weighted_return": -0.04420061615233983,
                            "inception_event_date": "2020-12-17",
                            "_custom_portfolio_target_347209": null,
                            "time_weighted_return_3": 0.07748325432684622,
                            "time_weighted_return_2": -0.04420061615233983,
                            "value": 6.014381761929752E7,
                            "node_id": null
                        },
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "entity_id": 9957007,
                                "name": "FW and FR Joint",
                                "grouping": "top_level_legal_entity",
                                "columns": {
                                    "time_weighted_return": null,
                                    "inception_event_date": "2021-12-21",
                                    "_custom_portfolio_target_347209": "N/A",
                                    "time_weighted_return_3": null,
                                    "time_weighted_return_2": null,
                                    "value": -1.44,
                                    "node_id": "9957007"
                                },
                                "children": []
                            },
                            {
                                "entity_id": 8413655,
                                "name": "FW Holdings No. 2 LLC",
                                "grouping": "top_level_legal_entity",
                                "columns": {
                                    "time_weighted_return": -0.0077309266066708515,
                                    "inception_event_date": "2021-03-05",
                                    "_custom_portfolio_target_347209": "N/A",
                                    "time_weighted_return_3": 0.11844843557716445,
                                    "time_weighted_return_2": -0.0077309266066708515,
                                    "value": 6768936.74,
                                    "node_id": "8413655"
                                },
                                "children": []
                            },
                            {
                                "entity_id": 13396796,
                                "name": "FW Liquid Fund LP",
                                "grouping": "top_level_legal_entity",
                                "columns": {
                                    "time_weighted_return": -0.04149769229150746,
                                    "inception_event_date": "2021-12-30",
                                    "_custom_portfolio_target_347209": "Aggressive",
                                    "time_weighted_return_3": -0.041497430478377395,
                                    "time_weighted_return_2": -0.04149769229150746,
                                    "value": 5.289952672686747E7,
                                    "node_id": "13396796"
                                },
                                "children": []
                            },
                            {
                                "entity_id": 13014080,
                                "name": "The FW Family Trust",
                                "grouping": "top_level_legal_entity",
                                "columns": {
                                    "time_weighted_return": -0.06102013456998856,
                                    "inception_event_date": "2021-04-09",
                                    "_custom_portfolio_target_347209": "Aggressive",
                                    "time_weighted_return_3": -0.039685671858585514,
                                    "time_weighted_return_2": -0.06102013456998856,
                                    "value": 475355.59242999996,
                                    "node_id": "13014080"
                                },
                                "children": []
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Portfolio_1",
                        "grouping": "_custom_new_entity_group_453577",
                        "columns": {
                            "time_weighted_return": -0.44554958179309,
                            "inception_event_date": "2021-04-07",
                            "_custom_portfolio_target_347209": "N/A",
                            "time_weighted_return_3": -0.44554958179309,
                            "time_weighted_return_2": -0.44554958179309,
                            "value": 260786.03,
                            "node_id": null
                        },
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "entity_id": 9552252,
                                "name": "The FW Irrev Family Tr",
                                "grouping": "top_level_legal_entity",
                                "columns": {
                                    "time_weighted_return": 0.0,
                                    "inception_event_date": "2022-01-11",
                                    "_custom_portfolio_target_347209": "N/A",
                                    "time_weighted_return_3": 0.0,
                                    "time_weighted_return_2": 0.0,
                                    "value": 260786.03,
                                    "node_id": "9552252"
                                },
                                "children": []
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Portfolio_2",
                        "grouping": "_custom_new_entity_group_453577",
                        "columns": {
                            "time_weighted_return": -0.05780354507057972,
                            "inception_event_date": "2021-09-03",
                            "_custom_portfolio_target_347209": "Growth",
                            "time_weighted_return_3": -0.05470214863844658,
                            "time_weighted_return_2": -0.05780354507057972,
                            "value": 1.8396664156520825E7,
                            "node_id": null
                        },
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "entity_id": 10946585,
                                "name": "FW DAF",
                                "grouping": "top_level_legal_entity",
                                "columns": {
                                    "time_weighted_return": -0.05780354507057972,
                                    "inception_event_date": "2021-09-03",
                                    "_custom_portfolio_target_347209": "Growth",
                                    "time_weighted_return_3": -0.05470214863844658,
                                    "time_weighted_return_2": -0.05780354507057972,
                                    "value": 1.8396664156520832E7,
                                    "node_id": "10946585"
                                },
                                "children": []
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "included": []
}
```

**My code:** this is the function, which I built to try and normalize the JSON response and save in a pandas dataframe -

```
def unpack_response():
    while True:
        try:    
            api_response = response_writer()
            df = pd.json_normalize(api_response['data']['attributes']['total']['children'])
            df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'columns.', '', regex=False)
            column_name_mapper = {column['key']: column['display_name'] for column in api_response['meta']['columns']}
            df.rename(columns=column_name_mapper, inplace=True)
            break
        except KeyError:
            print("-----------------------------------\n","API TIMEOUT ERROR: TRYING AGAIN...", "\n-----------------------------------\n")
    
    df.rename(columns={'name': 'New Entity Group'}, inplace=True)

    column_names = ["New Entity Group", "Entity ID", "Adjusted Value (1/31/2022, No Div, USD)", "Adjusted TWR (Current Quarter, No Div, USD)", "Adjusted TWR (YTD, No Div, USD)", "Annualized Adjusted TWR (Since Inception, No Div, USD)", "Inception Date"]
    df = df.reindex(columns=column_names)
    
    return df
unpack_response()
```

**Comment about my code:**

- **Portfolio_1, Portfolio_2, Portfolio_3** - these bolded rows are first level of `children` of `data` and seem to be the only rows which are saving to the `df`. I think this is because my code references `df = pd.json_normalize(api_response['data']['attributes']['total']['children'])` so is only looking at these lists. I tried just appending `['children']['children']` to the end of that code snippet (given there are 3x level of `children`, but received a `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`.

I would be grateful for any suggestions on how I can improve or add to my function, so I can tap into the key:pair values, which are the 2x lower of the `children` levels.

Comment: If I may ask, are you waiting for more answers? Does any particular answer seem better to you?

Comment: I apologize to all those who took incredible effort to contribute. I’ve spent the weekend reviewing and understanding all the code, before rewarding the bounty. I will do this shortly. Thank you everyone for being so generous with your answers and clear explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would not use `pd.json_normalize` for this case. Your JSON is quite complex, and unless you're really experienced with `json_normalize`, the following code may take less time to understand for the average dev. In fact, you don't even need to see the JSON to understand exactly what this code does (although it would certainly help ;).

First, we can extract the objects (portfolios and their children) from the JSON into a list, and use a series of steps to get them in the right form and order:

```
def prep_obj(o):
    """Prepares an object (portfolio/child) from the JSON to be inserted into a dataframe."""
    return {
        'New Entity Group': o['name'],
    } | o['columns']


# Get a list of lists, where each sub-list contains the portfolio object at index 0 and then the portfolio object's children:
groups = [[prep_obj(o), *[prep_obj(child) for child in o['children']]] for o in api_response['data']['attributes']['total']['children']]

# Sort the portfolio groups by their number:
groups.sort(key=lambda g: int(g[0]['New Entity Group'].split('_')[1]))

# Reverse the children of each portfolio group:
groups = [[g[0]] + g[1:][::-1] for g in groups]

# Flatten out the groups into one large list of objects:
objects = [obj for group in groups for obj in group]
# The above is exactly equivalent to the following:
#   objects = []
#   for group in groups:
#       for obj in group:
#           objects.append(obj)
```

Next, create the dataframe:

```
# Create a mapping for column names so that their display names can be used:
mapping = {col['key']: col['display_name'] for col in api_response['meta']['columns']}

# Create a dataframe from the list of objects:
df = pd.DataFrame(objects)

# Correct column names:
df = df.rename(mapping, axis=1)
# Reorder columns:
column_names = ["New Entity Group", "Entity ID", "Adjusted Value (1/31/2022, No Div, USD)", "Adjusted TWR (Current Quarter, No Div, USD)", "Adjusted TWR (YTD, No Div, USD)", "Annualized Adjusted TWR (Since Inception, No Div, USD)", "Inception Date", "Risk Target"]
df = df[column_names]
```

And formatting:

```
def format_twr_col(col):
    return (
        col
        .abs()
        .mul(100)
        .round(2)
        .pipe(lambda s: s.where(s.eq(0) | s.isna(), '(' + s.astype(str) + '%)'))
        .pipe(lambda s: s.where(s.ne(0) | s.isna(), s.astype(str) + '%'))
        .fillna('-')
    )

def format_value_col(col):
    positive_mask = col.ge(0)

    col[positive_mask] = (
        col[positive_mask]
        .round()
        .astype(int)
        .map('${:,}'.format)
    )

    col[~positive_mask] = (
        col[~positive_mask]
        .astype(float)
        .round()
        .astype(int)
        .abs()
        .map('(${:,})'.format)
    )
    
    return col

df['Adjusted TWR (Current Quarter, No Div, USD)'] = format_twr_col(df['Adjusted TWR (Current Quarter, No Div, USD)'])
df['Annualized Adjusted TWR (Since Inception, No Div, USD)'] = format_twr_col(df['Annualized Adjusted TWR (Since Inception, No Div, USD)'])
df['Adjusted TWR (YTD, No Div, USD)'] = format_twr_col(df['Adjusted TWR (YTD, No Div, USD)'])

df['Adjusted Value (1/31/2022, No Div, USD)'] = format_value_col(df['Adjusted Value (1/31/2022, No Div, USD)'].copy())

df['Inception Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Inception Date']).dt.strftime('%b %d, %Y')

df['Entity ID'] = df['Entity ID'].fillna('')
```

And... voilà:

```
>>> pd.options.display.max_columns = None
>>> df
         New Entity Group Entity ID Adjusted Value (1/31/2022, No Div, USD)  Adjusted TWR (Current Quarter, No Div, USD) Adjusted TWR (YTD, No Div, USD)  Annualized Adjusted TWR (Since Inception, No Div, USD) Inception Date  Risk Target
0             Portfolio_1                                          $260,786                                     (44.55%)                        (44.55%)                                            (44.55%)       Apr 07, 2021          N/A
1  The FW Irrev Family Tr   9552252                                $260,786                                         0.0%                            0.0%                                                0.0%       Jan 11, 2022          N/A
2             Portfolio_2                                       $18,396,664                                      (5.78%)                         (5.78%)                                             (5.47%)       Sep 03, 2021       Growth
3                  FW DAF  10946585                             $18,396,664                                      (5.78%)                         (5.78%)                                             (5.47%)       Sep 03, 2021       Growth
4             Portfolio_3                                       $60,143,818                                      (4.42%)                         (4.42%)                                             (7.75%)       Dec 17, 2020          NaN
5     The FW Family Trust  13014080                                $475,356                                       (6.1%)                          (6.1%)                                             (3.97%)       Apr 09, 2021   Aggressive
6       FW Liquid Fund LP  13396796                             $52,899,527                                      (4.15%)                         (4.15%)                                             (4.15%)       Dec 30, 2021   Aggressive
7   FW Holdings No. 2 LLC   8413655                              $6,768,937                                      (0.77%)                         (0.77%)                                            (11.84%)       Mar 05, 2021          N/A
8         FW and FR Joint   9957007                                    ($1)                                            -                               -                                                   -       Dec 21, 2021          N/A
```

Comment: I appreciate there is no obligation to reply, however how would I go a level deeper i.e., children contained children, that contained children. I tried something `api_response['data']['attributes']['total']['children']['children]` but as you can imagine, it didn't go well!

Comment: Hi @William, it's really late here, I'll try to get to you tomorrow. Unfortunately I'm off on a trip tomorrow for a week, so I may not get back until then :/

Answer (score 2):

Since your `children`'s `children` has same structure as `children`, you can try using `json_normalize` twice separately and append it together.

```py
# For first layer that includes Portfolio_1, Portfolio_2, Portfolio_3
df = pd.json_normalize(s, record_path=['data', 'attributes', 'total', 'children'])

# For second layer that includes The FW Irrev Family Tr, etc
# Use explode to convert list into rows
df_child = pd.json_normalize(df.explode('children').children)

# Combine both
df = pd.concat([df, df_child])

# You can use your column renaming and filtering
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks like you are trying to create and then stack three dataframes, which you may not really want to do or may be better achieved by mapping each **Porfolio_** to every relevant line and then either

```py
import itertools
...
portfolio_views_children = response['data']['attributes']['total']['children']

portfolios = []
for portfolio in portfolio_views_children:
    entity_columns = []
    # include portfolio itself within an iterable so the total is the header
    for entity in itertools.chain([portfolio], portfolio["children"]):
        entity_data = entity["columns"].copy()  # don't mutate original response
        entity_data["portfolio"] = portfolio["name"]   # from outer
        entity_data["name"]      = entity["name"]
        entity_columns.append(entity_data)

    df = pd.DataFrame(entity_columns)
    portfolios.append(df)

# combine dataframes
df = pd.concat(portfolios)
# reorder and rename
column_ordering = {"portfolio": "portfolio", "name": "name"}
column_ordering.update({c["key"]: c["display_name"] for c in response["meta"]["columns"]})
df = df[column_ordering.keys()]   # beware: un-named cols will be dropped
df = df.rename(columns=column_ordering)

print(df.to_markdown(index=False))  # create output below (requires tabulate)
```

| portfolio | name | Entity ID | Adjusted Value (1/31/2022, No Div, USD) | Adjusted TWR (Current Quarter, No Div, USD) | Adjusted TWR (YTD, No Div, USD) | Annualized Adjusted TWR (Since Inception, No Div, USD) | Inception Date | Risk Target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Portfolio_3 | Portfolio_3 |  | 6.01438e+07 | -0.0442006 | -0.0442006 | 0.0774833 | 2020-12-17 |  |
| Portfolio_3 | FW and FR Joint | 9957007 | -1.44 | nan | nan | nan | 2021-12-21 | N/A |
| Portfolio_3 | FW Holdings No. 2 LLC | 8413655 | 6.76894e+06 | -0.00773093 | -0.00773093 | 0.118448 | 2021-03-05 | N/A |
| Portfolio_3 | FW Liquid Fund LP | 13396796 | 5.28995e+07 | -0.0414977 | -0.0414977 | -0.0414974 | 2021-12-30 | Aggressive |
| Portfolio_3 | The FW Family Trust | 13014080 | 475356 | -0.0610201 | -0.0610201 | -0.0396857 | 2021-04-09 | Aggressive |
| Portfolio_1 | Portfolio_1 |  | 260786 | -0.44555 | -0.44555 | -0.44555 | 2021-04-07 | N/A |
| Portfolio_1 | The FW Irrev Family Tr | 9552252 | 260786 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2022-01-11 | N/A |
| Portfolio_2 | Portfolio_2 |  | 1.83967e+07 | -0.0578035 | -0.0578035 | -0.0547021 | 2021-09-03 | Growth |
| Portfolio_2 | FW DAF | 10946585 | 1.83967e+07 | -0.0578035 | -0.0578035 | -0.0547021 | 2021-09-03 | Growth |

Comment: Please accept my apologies for the delay thanking you for this contribution. My only question is - how would you expand this code to accommodate another hierarchy of children, all containing exactly the same data as the level above?

Comment: @William you should be able to continue adding them the `for` loop over `itertools.chain` - additionally, if you find you have a great or unknown depth of the same structure, you may find walking the structure recursively, calling `isinstance` and iterating for (`list`, `dict`) and checking tree nodes works very well (adding blocks that match to a collection to then iterate over)

Comment: thank you. I tried `for entity in itertools.chain([portfolio], portfolio["children"],["children"]):` however just got a 'TypeError: string indices must be integers'. Which is referencing `entity_data = entity["columns"].copy()` Did I approach this wrong?

Comment: To give additional context - I am able to access all levels by doing a simple `df = json_normalize(api_response['data']['attributes']['total']['children'], record_path = ['children', 'children', 'children'])` @ti7

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use `json_normalize`. The following code doesn't deal with error handling, detailed formatting, etc, whereas I think the essence of what you want to do the most is included.

#### Code:

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

# You have to change this path according to the actual json file location.
with open('./api_response.json', 'r') as f:
    api_response = json.load(f)

def unpack_response(r):
    df = pd.DataFrame()

    df_src = pd.json_normalize(r, record_path=['data', 'attributes', 'total', 'children'])
    for _, row in df_src.sort_values('name').iterrows(): 
        df_p = pd.DataFrame(row).T
        df_c = pd.json_normalize(row.children)

        # I'm not sure what your expected sorting order is. Perhaps you might want to delete the next line.
        df_c = df_c.sort_values(['columns._custom_portfolio_target_347209', 'columns.inception_event_date'])

        df = pd.concat([df, df_p, df_c], axis=0, ignore_index=True)

    column_name_mapper = {'columns.' + column['key']: column['display_name'] for column in api_response['meta']['columns']}
    column_name_mapper.update({'name': 'New Entity Group'})
    column_names = ["New Entity Group", "Entity ID", "Adjusted Value (1/31/2022, No Div, USD)", "Adjusted TWR (Current Quarter, No Div, USD)", "Adjusted TWR (YTD, No Div, USD)", "Annualized Adjusted TWR (Since Inception, No Div, USD)", "Inception Date", "Risk Target"]
    df = df.rename(columns=column_name_mapper).reindex(columns=column_names)

    return df

df = unpack_response(api_response)
```

#### Output:

| New Entity Group | Entity ID | Adjusted Value (1/31/2022, No Div, USD) | Adjusted TWR (Current Quarter, No Div, USD) | Adjusted TWR (YTD, No Div, USD) | Annualized Adjusted TWR (Since Inception, No Div, USD) | Inception Date | Risk Target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Portfolio_1 |  | 260786 | -0.44555 | -0.44555 | -0.44555 | 2021-04-07 | N/A |
| The FW Irrev Family Tr | 9552252 | 260786 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2022-01-11 | N/A |
| Portfolio_2 |  | 1.83967e+07 | -0.0578035 | -0.0578035 | -0.0547021 | 2021-09-03 | Growth |
| FW DAF | 10946585 | 1.83967e+07 | -0.0578035 | -0.0578035 | -0.0547021 | 2021-09-03 | Growth |
| Portfolio_3 |  | 6.01438e+07 | -0.0442006 | -0.0442006 | 0.0774833 | 2020-12-17 |  |
| The FW Family Trust | 13014080 | 475356 | -0.0610201 | -0.0610201 | -0.0396857 | 2021-04-09 | Aggressive |
| FW Liquid Fund LP | 13396796 | 5.28995e+07 | -0.0414977 | -0.0414977 | -0.0414974 | 2021-12-30 | Aggressive |
| FW Holdings No. 2 LLC | 8413655 | 6.76894e+06 | -0.00773093 | -0.00773093 | 0.118448 | 2021-03-05 | N/A |
| FW and FR Joint | 9957007 | -1.44 | nan | nan | nan | 2021-12-21 | N/A |